# I am using accordions is behaving weird and my textinput on that screen is not working either

Tags: python, kivy

On display screen of my code i have used accordions, I have done every thing as instructed and the code for `TextInput` in that page is right but accordions are not working as intended and the textInput is not taking any inputs. I am new to kivy and as far as I know every thing seems right to me.

Heres my code:

```
    import kivy
    kivy.require('1.10.0')

    from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.label import Label 
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup  
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 
    from kivy.lang import Builder 
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.properties import StringProperty


    import json

    Builder.load_file('VocabularyJournal.kv')

    class MenuPage(Screen):
        pass

    class DisplayPage(Screen):                   # here is the display page[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        search_box= ObjectProperty()
        label_maening=StringProperty()
        label_synonym=StringProperty()
        label_ant=StringProperty()
        label_sentence=StringProperty()


        def search_function(self):
            with open('vocab_words.json') as rfile:
                data=json.load(rfile)

            word=self.search_box.text 

            for value in data:
                if value['word']==word:
                    self.label_maening=value['meaning']
                    self.label_synonym=value['synonym']
                    self.label_ant=value['antonyms']
                    self.label_sentence=value['sentence']


    class WordInsertPage(Screen):
        pass


    class NewWordPage(Screen):
        word_box = ObjectProperty()
        meaning_box = ObjectProperty()
        synonym_box = ObjectProperty()
        ant_box = ObjectProperty()
        sentence_box = ObjectProperty()


        def saving_data(self):

            with open('vocab_words.json') as rfile:
                data=json.load(rfile)


            entry={'word': self.word_box.text, 'meaning': self.meaning_box.text, 'synonym': self.synonym_box.text, 'antonyms': self.ant_box.text, 'sentence': self.sentence_box.text}
            data.append(entry)


            with open('vocab_words.json','w') as wfile:
                json.dump(data,wfile,indent=4)


    class FlashCard(Screen):
        pass

    class WordGroups(Screen):
        pass

    class Manager(ScreenManager):
        pass

    class VocabularyJournalApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return Manager()

    object = VocabularyJournalApp()
    object.run()
```

heres the kivy code-

```
    <Manager>:
        MenuPage:
            name: 'menu'
        WordInsertPage:
            name: 'insertword'
        NewWordPage:
            name: 'newword'
        FlashCard:
            name: 'flashcard'
        WordGroups:
            name: 'wordgroup'
        DisplayPage:
            name: 'display'

    <MenuPage>:
        Label: 
            text: "Vocabulary Journal"
            size_hint: .90,.10

        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'tb-rl'
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10

            Button:
                text: 'Search'
                size_hint: None,.20
                width: 130
                background_down:'darkgrey.png'
                on_press: root.manager.current='insertword'
            Button:
                text: 'New Word'
                size_hint: None,.20
                width: 130
                background_down:'darkgrey.png'
                on_press: root.manager.current='insertword'
            Button:
                text: 'Flash Cards'
                size_hint: None,.20
                width: 130
                background_down:'darkgrey.png'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flashcard'

            Button:
                text: 'Word Groups'
                size_hint: None,.20
                width: 130
                background_down:'darkgrey.png'
                on_press: root.manager.current='wordgroup'

    <WordInsertPage>:

        FloatLayout:

            Button: 
                text: "New Word"
                on_press: root.manager.current='newword'
                font_size: 30
                color: 0,0,0,1
                size_hint: .2, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.3}
                background_down: 'darkgrey.png'
            Button:
                text: "search word"
                on_press: root.manager.current='display'
                font_size: 30
                color: 0,0,0,1
                size_hint: .2, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.5}
                background_down: 'darkgrey.png'
            Button:
                text: 'Flash Cards'
                on_press: root.manager.current="flashcard"
                font_size: 30
                color: 0,0,0,1
                size_hint: .2, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.7}
                background_down: 'darkgrey.png'



    <NewWordPage>:
        id: refer_to_it
        word_box: word_input
        meaning_box: meaning_input
        synonym_box: Synonym_input
        ant_box: ant_input
        sentence_box: sentence_input
        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'tb-rl'
            spacing: 10
            padding: 90
            TextInput:
                text: "write your word here"
                color: 1,1,1,1
                id: word_input
                width: 300
                size_hint: None, .10

            TextInput:
                text: "write meaning of your word here"
                color: 1,1,1,1
                id: meaning_input
                width: 600
                size_hint: None, .20

            TextInput:
                text: "write Synonyms of your word here"
                color: 1,1,1,1
                id: Synonym_input
                width: 600
                size_hint: None, .20

            TextInput:
                text: "write antonyms of your text here"
                color: 1,1,1,1
                id: ant_input
                width: 600
                size_hint: None, .20

            TextInput:
                text: "write a sentence based on your word here"
                color: 1,1,1,1
                id: sentence_input
                width: 600
                size_hint: None, .20

            Button:
                text: 'Save'
                size_hint: None,.10
                width: 130
                background_down:'darkgrey.png'
                on_press: refer_to_it.saving_data()     

    <DisplayPage>:                          # here is the display page
        search_box: search_text
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'

            TextInput:
                text:'enter the word you wanna search here'
                id: search_text
                on_text_validate: root.search_function()

        Accordion:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            AccordionItem:
                title:'meaning'

                Label:
                    text: root.label_maening
                    text_size: self.width, None

            AccordionItem:
                title:'Synonym'

                Label:
                    text: root.label_synonym
                    text_size: self.width, None

            AccordionItem:
                title:'Antonym'

                Label:
                    text: root.label_ant
                    text_size: self.width, None

            AccordionItem:
                title:'Sentence'

                Label:
                    text: root.label_sentence
                    text_size: self.width, None
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle I see three problems:

- `on_text_validate` **isn't fired in multiline inputs**. You should set `multiline` property to `False`.
- Use [hint_text](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.hint_text) property to set the suggestion text.
- The weird behavior of your accordion is probably caused because you are loading your kv file twice (Your `"Multiple screens named ..."` warnings are indicative of that.). I recommend renaming your kv to `vocabularyjournal.kv` and not using `Builder.load_file ()`. You can look at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695485/7131499).

**main.py:**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


import json


class MenuPage(Screen):
    pass

class DisplayPage(Screen):                  
    search_box= ObjectProperty()
    label_maening=StringProperty()
    label_synonym=StringProperty()
    label_ant=StringProperty()
    label_sentence=StringProperty()


    def search_function(self):
        with open('vocab_words.json') as rfile:
            data=json.load(rfile)

        word=self.search_box.text

        for value in data:
            if value['word']==word:
                self.label_maening=value['meaning']
                self.label_synonym=value['synonym']
                self.label_ant=value['antonyms']
                self.label_sentence=value['sentence']


class WordInsertPage(Screen):
    pass


class NewWordPage(Screen):
    word_box = ObjectProperty()
    meaning_box = ObjectProperty()
    synonym_box = ObjectProperty()
    ant_box = ObjectProperty()
    sentence_box = ObjectProperty()


    def saving_data(self):

        with open('vocab_words.json') as rfile:
            data=json.load(rfile)


        entry={'word': self.word_box.text, 'meaning': self.meaning_box.text, 'synonym': self.synonym_box.text, 'antonyms': self.ant_box.text, 'sentence': self.sentence_box.text}
        data.append(entry)


        with open('vocab_words.json','w') as wfile:
            json.dump(data,wfile,indent=4)


class FlashCard(Screen):
    pass

class WordGroups(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class VocabularyJournalApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

obj = VocabularyJournalApp()
obj.run()
```

**vocabularyjournal.kv:**

```
<Manager>:
    MenuPage:
        name: 'menu'
    WordInsertPage:
        name: 'insertword'
    NewWordPage:
        name: 'newword'
    FlashCard:
        name: 'flashcard'
    WordGroups:
        name: 'wordgroup'
    DisplayPage:
        name: 'display'

<MenuPage>:
    Label:
        text: "Vocabulary Journal"
        size_hint: .90,.10

    StackLayout:
        orientation: 'tb-rl'
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10

        Button:
            text: 'Search'
            size_hint: None,.20
            width: 130
            background_down:'darkgrey.png'
            on_press: root.manager.current='insertword'
        Button:
            text: 'New Word'
            size_hint: None,.20
            width: 130
            background_down:'darkgrey.png'
            on_press: root.manager.current='insertword'
        Button:
            text: 'Flash Cards'
            size_hint: None,.20
            width: 130
            background_down:'darkgrey.png'
            on_press: root.manager.current='flashcard'

        Button:
            text: 'Word Groups'
            size_hint: None,.20
            width: 130
            background_down:'darkgrey.png'
            on_press: root.manager.current='wordgroup'

<WordInsertPage>:

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            text: "New Word"
            on_press: root.manager.current='newword'
            font_size: 30
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: .2, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.3}
            background_down: 'darkgrey.png'
        Button:
            text: "search word"
            on_press: root.manager.current='display'
            font_size: 30
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: .2, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.5}
            background_down: 'darkgrey.png'
        Button:
            text: 'Flash Cards'
            on_press: root.manager.current="flashcard"
            font_size: 30
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: .2, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.7}
            background_down: 'darkgrey.png'



    <NewWordPage>:
        id: refer_to_it
        word_box: word_input
        meaning_box: meaning_input
        synonym_box: Synonym_input
        ant_box: ant_input
        sentence_box: sentence_input
        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'tb-rl'
            spacing: 10
            padding: 90
            TextInput:
                hint_text: "write your word here"
                color: 1,1,1,1
                id: word_input
                width: 300
                size_hint: None, .10

            TextInput:
                hint_text: "write meaning of your word here"
                color: 1,1,1,1
                id: meaning_input
                width: 600
                size_hint: None, .20

            TextInput:
                hint_text: "write Synonyms of your word here"
                color: 1,1,1,1
                id: Synonym_input
                width: 600
                size_hint: None, .20

            TextInput:
                hint_text: "write antonyms of your text here"
                color: 1,1,1,1
                id: ant_input
                width: 600
                size_hint: None, .20

            TextInput:
                hint_text: "write a sentence based on your word here"
                color: 1,1,1,1
                id: sentence_input
                width: 600
                size_hint: None, .20

            Button:
                hint_text: 'Save'
                size_hint: None,.10
                width: 130
                background_down:'darkgrey.png'
                on_press: refer_to_it.saving_data()

    <DisplayPage>:                          # here is the display page
        search_box: search_text
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'

            TextInput:
                hint_text:'enter the word you wanna search here'
                id: search_text
                multiline: False
                on_text_validate: root.search_function()

        Accordion:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            AccordionItem:
                title:'meaning'

                Label:
                    text: root.label_maening
                    text_size: self.width, None

            AccordionItem:
                title:'Synonym'

                Label:
                    text: root.label_synonym
                    text_size: self.width, None

            AccordionItem:
                title:'Antonym'

                Label:
                    text: root.label_ant
                    text_size: self.width, None

            AccordionItem:
                title:'Sentence'

                Label:
                    text: root.label_sentence
                    text_size: self.width, None
```

> **Note:** You shouldn't use `object` as variable name. It is a built-in function.